# How do I remove a prepending slash from an image path using fluid / vhs?

Tags: fluid, typo3-11.x

I am updating a project to TYPO3 11 and encountered the following problem:

The project uses `v:page.resources.fal` to retrieve images from other pages to be presented as teaser images. The image path gets rendered as `/path/to/file.jpg`.
Then using `v:media.exists` to check if an image exists, and when not, display a generic placeholder image.

Contrary to TYPO3 10, in 11 `v:media.exists` requires this path to be provided *without* a prepending slash: `path/to/file.jpg`. Breaking existing modules using this feature. (Absolute paths are also not accepted).

Is there an elegant way to remove a prepending slash without having to write a custom viewhelper?

Answer (score 0):

So the real question to my problem was "how do I check if a corresponding page has an image in resources".

Turns out, using VHS I can simply check the ID of the page, and see if there is a media count above 0:

```
<f:if condition="{v:page.info(pageUid: '{uid}', field: 'media')} > 0">
  <f:then>
    Show Image
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    Show Fallback
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

This circumvents my need for `v:media.exists` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a dataprocessor for that.
Here you can find a solution for Files (Images).

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/FilesProcessor.html